# Asymptotic behavior of $\cos(\sqrt{4n+1}x)-\cos(\sqrt{4n+\alpha}x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, asymptotics

While reading a paper in physics i came across asymptotic behavior of $\cos(\sqrt{4n+1}x)-\cos(\sqrt{4n+\alpha}x)$ and it was written this is equal to $O(n^{-1/4})$ for any real $\alpha$. I tried to prove this by considering the taylor expansion, but i couldn't get any result.

Any help is appreciated

[image: Clip from paper]

paper:http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375960111002970

Comment: I think you have a mistake. As your question stands, this is quite obviously false. Are you given anything about $x,n$ or $\alpha$?

Comment: we need to find as n tends to infinity

Comment: Using $\cos(A)-\cos(B)=-2\sin(\frac{A+B}{2})\sin(\frac{A-B}{2})$, at least we can show that the difference is $O(n^{-1/2})$.

Comment: which paper is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align} \cos{(\sqrt{2 n+1} x)} - \cos{(\sqrt{2 n+\alpha} x)} = -2 \sin{\left ( \frac{\sqrt{2 n+\alpha}-\sqrt{2 n+1}}{2} x \right )} \sin{\left ( \frac{\sqrt{2 n+\alpha}+\sqrt{2 n+1}}{2} x \right )}\\ \sim -\frac{\alpha - 1}{2} x \frac{\sin{(2 \sqrt{n} x)}}{2 \sqrt{n}} & (n \rightarrow \infty) \end{align}$$

No idea where you got the $O(n^{-1/4})$ thing.

Comment: can you explain your last step? also it implies $...\sim n^{-1/2}$ which is $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1/4})$, doesn't it?

Comment: For my last step, note that $\sqrt{n+a} - \sqrt{n} = a/(\sqrt{n+a} + \sqrt{n})$ (think difference of two squares).  As far as the $O(n^{-1/4})$ thing, yeah, you are technically correct, but it is wicked unhelpful.  Why not say $O(n^{-1/8})$ or $O(\log{\log{\log{n}}})$?  Again, why the particular order?

Comment: maybe the important fact for the paper he was reading was, that it is $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1/4})$, so they emphasized that point... I still don't see how you got rid of one $\sin$ though. Maybe you can add one or two steps inbetween?

Comment: ah, i think i got it. the first sin is very small (due to the $1/\sqrt{n}$) and can thus be approximated as $\sin(x)\sim x$.

Comment: Thanks @rlgordonma for your answer